# Check boxes search with Ransack gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, ransack, meta-search

I need to filter data in a table. To do this, I found [meta_search](https://github.com/ernie/meta_search) gem.
I installed meta_search and I get this error:

```
uninitialized constantActiveRecord::Associations::ClassMethods::JoinDependency
```

[This](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods/JoinDependency) is deprecated for Rails 4 (framework that I'm using). So, I installed [ransack (rails 4 branch)](https://github.com/ernie/ransack/tree/rails-4) (gem based on meta_search) and works beautifully. The problem is that I need to use the meta_search's [collection_checks](http://rdoc.info/github/ernie/meta_search/MetaSearch/Helpers/FormBuilder#collection_checks-instance_method) method to handle check boxes and this method does not exist in ransack. So, the question is:  there is a method in ransack similar to collection_checks to manage checkboxes? or how can I do this?

I have this:

[image]

And I want to filter and get rows with cars, bikes or both

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I'm not familiar with meta search but in Ransack (in Rails 4) you can use something like this:

MODELS:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :user_vehicles 
  has_many :vehicles, through: :user_vehicles
end

class UserVehicle < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :vehicle
end

class Vehicle < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :user_vehicles
end
```

Controller:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @q = User.search(params[:q])
    @users = @q.result(distinct: true)
  end
end
```

View:

```
<%= search_form_for @q , url: users_path, :html => { class: 'your-class' } do |f| %>
  <% Vehicle.all.each do |vehicle| %>
     <%= check_box_tag('q[vehicles_id_eq_any][]', vehicle.id ) %>
     <%= vehicle.name %>
  <% end %>
  <%= f.submit "Search" %>
<% end %>

<%= paginate(@users) %>
  <ul>
    <% @users.each do |i| %>
      <li><%= i.name %></li>
    <% end %>
  </ul>
<%= paginate(@users) %>
```

You can also use gem for pagination if you still don't use one. I use Kaminari. In this case your controller and view could look like this:

Controller:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @q = User.search(params[:q])
    @users = @q.result(distinct: true).page params[:page]
  end
end
```

View:

```
<%= search_form_for @q , url: users_path, :html => { class: 'your-class' } do |f| %>
  <% Vehicle.all.each do |vehicle| %>
     <%= check_box_tag('q[vehicles_id_eq_any][]', vehicle.id ) %>
     <%= vehicle.name %>
  <% end %>
  <%= f.submit "Search" %>
<% end %>

<%= paginate(@users) %>
  <ul>
    <% @users.each do |i| %>
      <li><%= i.name %></li>
    <% end %>
  </ul>
<%= paginate(@users) %>
```