# Ruby on Rails / Ransack: filter alls objects belonging to current user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ransack

Say I have a list of posts that I want to filter using Ransack. My view template looks like this (I use simple_form):

posts.haml:

```
= search_form_for @q, class: "form" do |f|
  # this works if enabled but sure enough fails if disabled
  # = f.input :user_id_eq, as: :boolean, value: current_user.id, label: "Show only my posts"
  = f.input :title_cont, required: false
  %button{type: "submit"} Search
```

user.rb

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :posts
end
```

post.rb

```
class Post < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
end
```

[edit: added models and half working solution]

Now I want to add a checkbox to filter the posts of the current user, like so: `[ ] Show only my posts`.
I have an association in place: user has_many posts / post belongs_to user

How can I add a checkbox to my ransack form to filter for all posts associated with the current user?

Comment: The question here should help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19560269/2545197

Comment: Can you please update your question with Post and User model code?

Comment: @Ami Edits: Added models and attempted solution (see commented code).

Comment: can you please elaborate this comment`# this works if enabled but sure enough fails if disabled` ?